# Why is shower head flow uneven with lots of water not coming through spray holes?

Tags: plumbing, water, shower, heater

Replaced water heater, so water main was shut off.  First time using shower had a  lot of water flowing out the side of the shower head, not through the spray holes.  Hand held shower head works fine.  Suspect sediment, but could use some help,  Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like sediment.  Soak the head in a bowl of vinegar for a few minutes.

Comment: @crip659 this would qualify as answer

Comment: I suspect your suspicion is correct.

Comment: next time, and to folks reading this, run a _bunch_ of water through the tub spout as fast as possible after changing a hot water heater, re-opening a disconnect valve, adding a water softener, etc; this releases all the particles through the big fat opening so that they don't find their way into faucet screens, icemakers, april aires, irrigation, showerheads, etc.

Answer (score 3):

It's quite likely that changing out the water heater mobilized a good amount of sediment, scale, sand, etc. that had collected in the lines.  The "shock" of re-applying water pressure and flow pushed that up and into your shower head.

You *may* be able to get it out by removing the shower head from the hose and trying to back-flush it with some clean water.  Soaking it in white vinegar may also help dissolve any mineral sediment that is there.

Hopefully that will clear it up but if not, then you may need to replace the shower head.

It's always a good idea to remove filters, screens, and things like your shower head and flush the lines after having to perform maintenance like you did.  If you have some other fixtures that have not yet been used, you might do that proactively rather than risk clogging them also.